# HTTParty ' get ' returns nil : Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, web-deployment, httparty

I'm new to Ruby on Rails framework. I was doing a practice exercise from a Ruby on Rails tutorial on coursera for which I had to get information about some courses from Coursera API using HTTParty and display this info on screen. But unfortunately I got stuck in a problem.

Here is my code that gets information from Coursera API and returns it

```
class Coursera
     include HTTParty

     base_uri 'https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses'
     default_params fields: "smallIcon,shortDescription", q: "search"
     format :json

     def self.for term
         response=get("", query: { query: term})["elements"]
         if(response==nil)
             puts "Got Negative response!"
         else
             puts "Got Positive response!"
             return response
         end
     end
 end
```

Can somebody point out why is 'get' returning nil. I'm sure I'm making some blunder but can somebody point it out? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd recommend reducing your code to the basic `HTTParty.get(...)['elements']` which works, then moving forward until it breaks again.

Answer (score 0):

Weird. It looks like coursera doesn't always return the same response.

```
require 'httparty'

class Coursera
  include HTTParty

  base_uri 'https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses'
  default_params fields: "smallIcon,shortDescription", q: "search"
  format :json

  def self.for term
    response = get("", query: {query: term})
    puts response.request.last_uri.to_s
    elements = response["elements"]
    if elements
      puts "Got Positive response!"
      response
    else
      puts "Got Negative response!"
    end
  end
end

p Coursera.for 'python'
```

Sometimes returns :

```
https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses?fields=smallIcon%2CshortDescription&q=search&query=python
Got Negative response!
nil
```

and sometimes :

```
https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses?fields=smallIcon%2CshortDescription&q=search&query=python
Got Positive response!
#<HTTParty::Response:0x2660970 parsed_response={"elements"=>[{"id"=>119, "shortName"=>"scicomp", "name"=>"High Performance Scientific Computing", "shortDescription"=>"Programming-oriented course on effectively using modern computers to solve scientific computing problems arising in the physical/engineering sciences and other fields. Provides an introduction to efficient serial and parallel computing using Fortran 90, OpenMP, MPI, and Python, and software development tools such as version control, Makefiles, and debugging.", "smallIcon"=>"https://d15cw65ipctsrr.cloudfront.net/00/621b9b2597807229ed0fa605f96cdc/HighPerformanceComputingIma.jpg", "links"=>{}}, {"id"=>87, "shortName"=>"compphoto", "name"=>"Computational Photography", "shortDescription"=>"In this course you will learn about the basics of 
....
```

Comment: I've seen that occur on other sites. My guess has always been that they're behind a load-balancer, and didn't update all their machines to the same version. Basically they have inconsistencies in their hosts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Eric. I've tested your code and it is always giving "Got Positive response" on my system. That's good but the problem is when I call this code in my Rails application, I always get "nil" returned by "get" function. (There is a controller called coursera_controller that calls the "for" function in code I wrote above with some parameter. A view gets the information from controller and presents on screen).